# When dynamically appending script into iframe, Content Security Policy isn't updated

Tags: javascript, iframe, content-security-policy

I want to dynamically append a script tag into my website.

The `src` needs to be dynamic, where a variable determines what subdomain to request the script from. Due to the unique nature of my site, This is my CSP policy:

```js
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; worker-src 'none'; navigate-to 'none';
```

I am trying to add a script, using this code:

```js
let subdomain = // my logic

let my_frame = document.createElement("iframe");
my_frame.csp = "script-src *.example.com";
document.body.appendChild(my_frame);

my_frame.contentWindow.document.write(`<script src="//${subdomain}.example.com"></script>`);
```

This code errors out:

[image: cant load script because it violates CSP directive unsafe-eval]

From what I understand about CSP, more restrictive directives take precendence. Since `script-src *.example.com` is more restrictive than `unsafe-eval`and `self`, my subdomain should be allowed. I will never use `example.com` alone, so I have only added the directive for the subdomain.

What is going wrong here?

*Note: I cannot change the current Content Security Policy.*

Comment: A small, or rather huge, note: don't use `document.write` to add content to an _already loaded document_. It's an incredibly archaic, low level function that does not "append data to a document", it interrupts a document byte stream and injects new bytes into it. And if the document was already done, that means building a _new, empty_ byte stream that is used to _rebuild_ the document. Now you have an empty document with a single script element in it. If you need the iframe to do something, consider a proper postMessage mechanism.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for the insight. now that i think about it, a postMessage system would be beneficial, i'll work to set it up. however, now i am kind of curious as to if a solution exists to this error. thanks again.

Comment: One thing to note is that your CSP currently does not include `*.example.com`, so I'd start there. Also note that `*.example.com` should _not_ match `example.com` because there is no tertiary domain, but _should_ match `www.example.com` and the like.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans "I will never use example.com alone, so I have only added the directive for the subdomain." I will only use subdomains, so this glob should match the subdomain as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes but look at your error, because it's telling you what CSP rule you gave it, and it's only unsafe-eval and self. So even if you think you added it, the error and your code say you didn't (which the first code block shows too, of course. There's only `script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'self';` =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Would the lack of `*.example.com` mean that the CSP directive is not being added for the contents of the iframe?

Comment: indeed. The only rule for iframes is the `iframe-src` rule, which specifies what on page iframes can do. They, in turn load _new documents_ that are independent of the parent, and so they will use a CSP that is "whatever _that_ URL's server specified".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans since the iframe-src rule falls back to default-src in this case, i don't see any way to load other documents. also, I realized that 'self' is more restrictive than '*.example.com', so i don't think this works. Just to see if the CSP is even working on the iframe, i set `style-src` to `*.example.com` , but i recieved the same error using a link inside of the iframe. As far as i can tell, the CSP isn't setting any values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257216/discussion-between-mike-pomax-kamermans-and-divinelemon).

Comment: Yes, because the iframe is loading a new document, with its own CSP. It doesn't matter what the parent document's CSP is, that policy can only dictate what gets set as iframe src, not anything about what happens _inside_ that iframe. The document inside the iframe is an independent document, exactly as if you loaded its src in a normal tab or window, and whatever is serving up the page that's getting loaded by the iframe needs its own CSP set appropriately.